# Redirect debugging output in OpenSSH

Tags: perl, openssh

I'm working on a program that runs interactive commands via OpenSSH and I can't figure out how I'm going to redirect the debugging output to debug.txt.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;                                                 
use Net::OpenSSH;

my ($u_name, $acc_name, $acc_uid);

print "Enter account ID: ";
$acc_uid = <STDIN>;
chomp ($acc_uid);

print "Login as: ";
$u_name = <STDIN>;
chomp ($u_name);

my $createuser = "sudo useradd $acc_uid";

system ("clear");

BEGIN { 
    open (my $out, '>>', '/usr/local/debug.txt') or warn $!;
    $Net::OpenSSH::debug_fh = $out;
    $Net::OpenSSH::debug = 16;
}  

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( "$u_name\@myserver", strict_mode => 0);

$ssh->system({tty => 1 }, "$createuser") 
                or die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;
```

I found the code for Net::OpenSSH::debug in [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#DEBUGGING) and this is the output of the program:

```
Enter account ID: usertest
Login as: testuser
# open_ex: ['ssh','-V']
# _waitpid(711) => pid: 711, rc:
testuser@myserver's password:
# open_ex: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/testuser-myserver-344-438107','-l','testuser','myserver','--']
# _waitpid(349) => pid: 349, rc:
# open_ex: ['ssh','-qtt','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/testuser-myserver-344-438107','-l','testuser','myserver','--','sudo useradd testuser123']
[sudo] password for testuser:
# _waitpid(350) => pid: 350, rc:
# open_ex: ['ssh','-O','exit','-T','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/testuser-myserver-344-438107','-l','testuser','myserver','--']
# _waitpid(351) => pid: 351, rc:
```

And when I checked debug.txt, it's empty. Thank you!

Comment: and so, what is your issue?

Comment: @salva I edited my question. Sorry I forgot to include the issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text. What exactly do you mean by "this is the output of the program"? How are you running it? Is this what's printed to the console? Have you checked whether it's stdout/stderr/something else? Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: @melpomene I've included the complete code and its output. Thanks

Comment: That output doesn't match your code.

Comment: @melpomene what do you mean the output doesn't match my code? I got that output from running the code above.

Comment: Then where's the `Enter account ID:` part?

Comment: Which version of `Net::OpenSSH` are you using? (If you're not sure, changing the `use` line to `use Net::OpenSSH 999;` should give you a helpful error message.)

Comment: @melpomene The version is 0.62. The `Enter account ID:` part was before the SSH, I've included it in the output. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> The version is 0.62.

As the [changelog](https://metacpan.org/source/SALVA/Net-OpenSSH-0.78/Changes#L86) explains:

> **0.66  Oct 11, 2015**
>
> - documentation fix (reported by Alex Kok)
> - allow redirecting debug output to a custom file handle

`$Net::OpenSSH::debug_fh` is only supported in Net::OpenSSH 0.66+. In older versions it always logs to `STDERR`.

Comment: I did not see that. Works perfectly now. Thanks!